# Why is this polynomial factorizable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials

I met a curious problem on factorizing a homogenerous polynomial of degree 9.

**Problem: Show that the following polynomial can be divided by $(a_1+a_2+a_3)$:**

\begin{align}
&\quad\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
 c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{array}
\right|^3 \\ &
+ \left(
 a_1^3 \left(b_2 c_3-b_3 c_2\right)
+a_2^3 \left(b_3 c_1-b_1 c_3\right)
+a_3^3 \left(b_1 c_2-b_2 c_1\right)
\right)\left(b_1+b_2+b_3\right)^2\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right)^2 \\
&- \left(
 b_1 \left(c_2 a_3-c_3 a_2\right)^3
+b_2 \left(c_3 a_1-c_1 a_3\right)^3
+b_3 \left(c_1 a_2-c_2 a_1\right)^3
\right)
\left(b_1+b_2+b_3\right)^2 \\
&- \left(
 c_1 \left(a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2\right)^3
+c_2 \left(a_3 b_1-a_1 b_3\right)^3
+c_3 \left(a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1\right)^3
\right)
\left(c_1+c_2+c_3\right)^2 
\end{align}

Mathematica  tells me it is true(one factor is $(a_1+a_2+a_3)$ while the other factor consists  of more than 200 terms), but I can not figure out a human proof.

Comment: can you disclose how this lengthy expression originates? that will likely be helpful to answering your question.

Comment: It is no factor.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What "clever way" you look for, and why using Mathematica is not one?

Comment: I guess the whole expression can be written as the determinant of a $3\times 3$ block matrix with $3\times 3$ elements similar to the given $3\times 3$ matrix. It looks like a (block) Laplace expansion. Btw, I LaTeX'd the expression.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev I mean a  human proof rather than computer check.

Comment: @LichenSDU A *human proof* for a non-human polynomial ...?

Comment: @Peter Mueller  Maybe this is what mathematics is about?

Comment: Mathematica says a1+a2+a3 is no factor: PolynomialRemainder[
 Det[{{a1, a2, x}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}]^3 // Expand, 
 a1 + a2 + x, x] does not give zero.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen The determinant is of course not divisible by $a_1+a_2+a_3$. However, the total sum (in 4 lines) is divisible by $a_1+a_2+a_3$. I checked it with Mathematica myself.

Comment: Did you try using the following?  $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
 c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_1+a_2+a_3 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 b_1+b_2+b_3 & b_2 & b_3 \\
 c_1+c_2+c_3 & c_2 & c_3 \\
\end{array}\right|\equiv -(b_1+b_2+b_3)(a_2c_3-a_3c_2)+(c_1+c_2+c_3)(a_2b_3-a_3b_2) \mod a_1+a_2+a_3$$

Comment: Looks like a normal question for me, why close?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: the problem with this question in my view is that we cannot give an "enlightening" proof of the factorizability of this polynomial without a better understanding of where it came from, which the question-asker refuses to provide.

Comment: @LichenSDU Try to formulate your problem for arbitrary $m$. This might give hints for a simpler representation of your polynomial (maybe as one determinant), and for a factorization.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins ,@Carlo Beenakker: see the update

Comment: @Fred Hucht It will be desirable to have a big determinant absorbing everything.

Comment: @Yaakov Baruch:This looks quite promising!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea that should lead to a human way to verify this.

Take a triple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ for which $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$. For example, $a_1=a=-a_2$, and $a_3=0$ or  $a_i=a\cdot\omega^i$ where $\omega^3=1$, $\omega\neq 1$, etc. Substitute these to your equation. If you can verify that that's zero, then you are in business. This should be a calculation that can be reasonably carried out by a human if needed. It involves expanding a few binomials to the third power and sorting out the terms.
These should work for an indeterminate $a$, which shows that the zero set of the polynomial $a_1+a_2+a_3$ is contained in the zero set of your big polynomial over any field. Then you get that the polynomial $a_1+a_2+a_3$ divides your big polynomial over any algebraically closed field by the Hilbert Nullstellensatz (because $a_1+a_2+a_3$, having degree $1$ is irreducible over any field).
Finally that (should?) imply that it divides it over $\mathbb Z$ as well (this should be checkable directly given that the dividing poly is linear with all (non-zero) coefficients being $1$). One could also try to use the Euclidean algorithm for checking this.

Comment: But $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ is a plane, whereas you suggest to verify the vanishing only on a line contained in that plane. Surely that's a bit too much simplification?

Comment: Well, that was preceded by the words "for example"... Also, you can surely rotate the conditions around, so that means at least 3 lines... :) You can use some other lines until you get more than 9.